# Find number of documents in a collection in Marklogic7 using Marklogic Rest API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-7

I am using Marklogic 7 Rest API and I want to find out the number of documents in any collection in my Marklogic database. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can POST a query on the collection with a page length of 1:

{"query": {
    "queries": [{
      "collection-query": {
        "uri": ["YOUR_COLLECTION"]
      }
    }]
    }}

http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/search

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_76890

The total property in the search response will indicate the number of documents in the collection.